# Active Record Where Not boolean: true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm struggling to wrap my mind around an ActiveRecord query.

I'm trying to search my database for GolfRetailer objects with ID's 1..100, that have something (not `nil`) in their `:website` field, and that don't have `true` in their `duplicate_domain` field.

Here's the query I expected to work:

`GolfRetailer.where.not(website: nil, duplicate_domain: true).where(id: 1..100)`

I also tried this variant of essentially the same query: `GolfRetailer.where.not(website: nil).where(id: 1..100, duplicate_domain: !true)`

But both return an empty array, despite there definitely being records that meet those requirements.

When I run `GolfRetailer.where.not(website: nil).where(id: 1..100)` I get an array, and when I run `GolfRetailer.where.not(website: nil, duplicate_domain: nil).where(id: 1..100)` I also get an array, but with all records that *do* have the true duplicate_domain flag, which isn't what I'm looking for.

I'd rather not search for records that have `duplicate_domain: nil` as that's not always correct (I may not have processed their domain yet).

For clarity, here is the Schema for the Model.

```
create_table "golf_retailers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "place_id"
    t.string "website"
    t.string "formatted_address"
    t.string "google_places_name"
    t.string "email"
    t.boolean "duplicate_domain"
    t.index ["duplicate_domain"], name: "index_golf_retailers_on_duplicate_domain"
  end
```

What am I missing to make this query work?

Comment: I would suggest a default of `false` for the `duplicate_domain` attribute. You could make this retroactive by adding `GolfRetailer.where(duplicate_domain: nil).update_all(duplicate_domain: false)`. Once the only options are true or false then the first query should work fine. The problem is right now this is 3 state (true, false, or nil) and not(true) does not equal NULL in SQL.

Comment: I would strongly recommend switching to `t.boolean "duplicate_domain", null: false` for the column, `null` in a boolean column is rarely what you want. Also, indexing a boolean column (or any low cardinality column) probably won't help, check the EXPLAIN output on your queries to see if that index ever gets used.

Comment: These comments were helpful in giving me a better insight in good design. Thank you for taking the time to explain that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is happening because in SQL when you do a `!= TRUE`, any `NULL` values will not be included in the result. This is because the `NULL` value represents an *unknown value*, so the DB does not know how to do any [comparison operations](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-comparison.html) on an unknown value and therefore they're excluded.

One way to get around this is to use [`IS DISTINCT FROM`](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Is_distinct_from):

```rb
GolfRetailer
  .where(id: 1..100)
  .where.not(website: nil)
  .where("duplicate_domain IS DISTINCT FROM ?", true)
```

---

As others have mentioned, you should also ask yourself if it's really the case that it's ever unknown to you if a `GolfRetailer` has a `duplicate_domain`.

If, all `GolfRetailer`s with a `duplicate_domain` of `NULL` actually mean they don't have one (`false`) than you should consider preventing a `NULL` value for that column entirely.

You can do this by adding a NOT NULL constraint on the column with a [`change_column` database migration](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#changing-columns).

In order to add the NOT NULL constraint you will first need to make sure all of the data in the column has non-null values.

```rb
def change
  GolfRetailer.in_batches.update_all(duplicate_domain: false)

  change_column_null :golf_retailers, :duplicate_domain
end
```

If your application is under load, you should also be careful about the potential performance any migration like this might have - notably if you add a NOT NULL constraint with a default value.

Consider using something like the [Strong Migrations](https://github.com/ankane/strong_migrations) gem to help find DB migrations that might cause downtime before production.